# numpy more efficient submatrix

Tags: python, numpy

Currently I am using the below code to get the submatrix with ith row and jth column removed, but after profiling my code, it seems to be one of the main bottlenecks in my code.  Is there a more efficient way?

```
def submatrix(A, i, j):
    logger.debug('submatrix(%r, %r, %r)', A, i, j)
    B = empty(shape=tuple(x - 1 for x in A.shape), dtype=int)
    B[:i, :j] = A[:i, :j]
    B[i:, :j] = A[i+1:, :j]
    B[:i, j:] = A[:i, j+1:]
    B[i:, j:] = A[i+1:, j+1:]
    return B

         25015049 function calls (24599369 primitive calls) in 44.587 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  3983040   15.541    0.000   20.719    0.000 defmatrix.py:301(__getitem__)
   415680   10.216    0.000   33.069    0.000 hill.py:127(submatrix)
 415686/6    3.232    0.000   44.578    7.430 hill.py:112(det)
```

Edit: Jaime has provided a good way to approximate modular inverses using the regular inverse and determinant, however with large bases (modulo 256 in my case), the inaccuracy is enough to render the the whole thing moot.  The main time sink appears to actually be **getitem** in numpy, but I believe that is caused by these lines:

```
    B[:i, :j] = A[:i, :j]
    B[i:, :j] = A[i+1:, :j]
    B[:i, j:] = A[:i, j+1:]
    B[i:, j:] = A[i+1:, j+1:]
```

It's possible the bottle-neck isn't copying matrices around in memory, but matrix entry access.

Comment: As @Bitwise points out in his answer, not much speed up to be gained in moving memory around. You could do at least 25% less shuffling of data by doing the operation in place, is that an option? Also, what do you need this submatrix for? It may be easier to modify the code using the submatrices to ignore the corresponding row and column than to actually remove them.

Comment: Would it be possible to generate a submatrix view?  I don't really need a copy of the submatrix, but I'm not sure if it's possible to arbitrarily slice up a matrix, as I'm not familiar with numpy.

Comment: In general no, you can't take a view of the submatrix. What are you doing with the submatrix afterwards?

Comment: I need it to calculate the modular minor, for finding the modular inverse.

Comment: It is very prone to rounding errors, but you could try to compute the [adjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of your matrix (what you divide by the determinant to get the inverse) as `np.linalg.inv(A) * np.linalg.det(A)`, which will make your code run a zillion times faster. What size matrices are you dealing with?

Comment: I'm looking for the modular inverse, so inv * det won't work (I think, modular arithmetic is not one of my strong points either).  I'm looking at matrices about 10~12 squared, but the faster the better, regardless of size.

Comment: It will work, unless there's rounding errors, will post as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... you are only copying matrices, so it will probably be difficult to speed up much, but one thing you can try is to verify that A is in a contiguous block of memory, which could speed access by the C code. Look at [numpy.ascontiguousarray()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `submatrix` just deletes the `i`th row and `j`th column.  You can do this with `np.delete`

```
i = 3
j = 4
a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
b = np.delete(np.delete(a, i, 0), j, 1)
```

But, for the rason @Jaime cites, this is actually slower `:-/`

```
timeit submatrix(a, i, j)
#10000 loops, best of 3: 23.2 us per loop

timeit subdel(a, i, j)
#10000 loops, best of 3: 42.6 us per loop
```

But I'll leave this here for now.

Comment: That will create an intermediate array without the `i`-th row, then remove its `j`-th column, so it will probably be twice as slow.

Comment: @Jaime you're right I just timed it.  Can delete take a row and a column?

Answer (score 1):

Computing the inverse of a matrix using determinants is a very slow approach, regardless of how you do the submatrices. Lets take a silly example:

```
a = np.array([[3, 0, 2],
              [2, 0, -2],
              [0, 1, 1]])
```

You can compute the inverse quickly as:

```
>>> np.linalg.inv(a)
array([[ 0.2,  0.2,  0. ],
       [-0.2,  0.3,  1. ],
       [ 0.2, -0.3, -0. ]])
```

But to compute a modular inverse, you need to have it as an integer matrix divided by an integer factor. That integer factor will of course be the determinant, so you can do the following:

```
>>> np.linalg.inv(a) * np.linalg.det(a)
array([[  2.,   2.,   0.],
       [ -2.,   3.,  10.],
       [  2.,  -3.,  -0.]])
```

And the inverse of `a` is this integer matrix, divided by the determinant of `a`. As a function, you could do:

```
def extended_euclidean_algorithm(a, b) :
    """
    Computes a solution to a x + b y = gcd(a,b), as well as gcd(a,b),
    using the extended Euclidean algorithm.
    """
    if b == 0 :
        return 1, 0, a
    else :
        x, y, gcd = extended_euclidean_algorithm(b, a % b)
        return y, x - y * (a // b), gcd

def mmi(a, m) :
    """
    Computes the modular multiplicative inverse of a modulo m, using the
    extended Euclidean algorithm.
    """
    x, y, gcd = extended_euclidean_algorithm(a, m)
    if gcd == 1 :
        return x % m
    else :
        return None

def modular_inv(a, m):
    det_a = np.linalg.det(a)
    inv_a = np.linalg.inv(a) * det_a
    det_a = np.rint(det_a).astype(int)
    inv_a = np.rint(inv_a).astype(int)
    return ((inv_a % m) * mmi(det_a, m)) % m
```

And now:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))
>>> b = modular_inv(a, 7)
>>> a.dot(b) % 7
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: This sounds great, but I think because I'm working in modulo 256 the float inprecision is nuking the answer.